# How to access Session variables and set them in javascript without using viewbag in .net core 3.1?

Tags: javascript, .net, session-variables, asp.net-core-3.1

I have been trying to access the session values in the javascript

I have tried using

```
var someSessionVariable = '@Session["SomeSessionVariable"]'
```

but no luck in accessing the values